# Generic function that can be called in in multiple Views

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement a generic function that can be used on multiple buttons.

```
binding.btn1.setOnClickListener { sharedFunction()}
binding.btn2.setOnClickListener { sharedFunction()}
binding.btn3.setOnClickListener { sharedFunction()}

fun sharedFunction(p0: View){
           binding.p0?.id.text = "Hello"
        }
```

My problem is, that i can't figure out how to write an generic line for the binding.

```
binding.p0?.id.text = "Hello"
```

Does not work, it does not recognize p0?.id as the View id.

My wish would be, that if button1 is clicked it would be called as

```
binding.p0?.id.text = "Hello" -> binding.btn1.text = "Hello"
```

and if button2 is clicked

```
binding.p0?.id.text = "Hello" -> binding.btn2.text = "Hello"
```

I know i can handle this with a switch() {} statement, but the code would be quite inelegant if i would copy for every case the same exact code just with different button bindings.

Is there a way i can set a placeholder for the ViewId in

```
binding.[placeholder].text = "Hello"
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that to be generic, you cannot really access it by 'binding', because you would look for a specific view. The generics work with definitions rather than IDs.

If you have the View argument (p0), that's all you need. Just use it like this:

```
fun sharedFunction(p0: View) {
    (p0 as Button).text = "Hello"
}
```

I have casted the View argument to the Button class, but double check what your buttons actually are.

Also keep in mind that you need to pass that View argument:

```
binding.btn1.setOnClickListener { view -> sharedFunction(view) }
binding.btn2.setOnClickListener { view -> sharedFunction(view) }
binding.btn3.setOnClickListener { view -> sharedFunction(view) }
```

**Bonus**

If you want to simplify your code, wrap it in scope function:

```
binding.apply {
    btn1.setOnClickListener { view -> sharedFunction(view) }
    btn2.setOnClickListener { view -> sharedFunction(view) }
    btn3.setOnClickListener { view -> sharedFunction(view) }
}
```

If you want to make an impression, try this code:

```
listOf(btn1, btn2, btn3).forEach {
    it.setOnClickListener { view -> sharedFunction(view) }
}
```